# Application Insights Log Query Get Latest Row in a Group

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to find the latest row of each member of a group in Application Insights.

Here's the query:

```
traces | 
where timestamp > ago(1h) | 
where message startswith "TEST DONE" | 
order by timestamp desc nulls last |  
extend json=parse_json(substring(message,10))  | 
summarize  any(timestamp, tostring(json.status)) by tostring(json.testKey)
```

It does return just one row but it's not the latest, it's any random row from the set of possible rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `arg_max` function?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction

something like:

```
traces | 
where timestamp > ago(1h) | 
where message startswith "TEST DONE" | 
order by timestamp desc nulls last |  
extend json=parse_json(substring(message,10))  | 
extend testKey = tostring(json.testKey) |
extend status = tostring(json.status) |
summarize arg_max(timestamp, status) by testKey
```

Comment: Thank you.  Also, I finally found the Kusto language reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use makelist([column name], 1) to pick the first one. Then refer to it by index. Using this technique was able to solve above problem on my dataset.

Here is adaptation to your query:

```
traces | 
where timestamp > ago(1h) | 
where message startswith "TEST DONE" | 
order by timestamp desc nulls last |  
extend json=parse_json(substring(message,10))  | 
extend testKey = tostring(json.testKey) |
summarize timeStampList=makelist(timestamp, 1), statusList=makelist(tostring(json.status), 1) by testKey |
project timeStampList[0], statusList[0], testKey
```